# Conditional Logical Form to Calculate Product Price Based On Customer Input From Form In WordPress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to implement conditional logic for product price based on color, fabric etc and display price to customer based on their input in Wordpress. For one product its working and giving price but for multiple product its showing undefined index.

I will attach both the code i used

Single Product Code:

```
// Add a shortcode for the T-shirt pricing form
function tshirt_pricing_form_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="size">Size:</label>
        <select name="size" required>
            <option value="small">Small</option>
            <option value="medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="large">Large</option>
            <option value="xl">XL</option>
        </select>

        <label for="color">Color:</label>
        <select name="color" required>
            <option value="white">White</option>
            <option value="black">Black</option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        </select>

        <label for="custom_printing">Custom Printing:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="custom_printing">

        <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
        <input type="number" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" required>

        <input type="submit" value="Calculate Price">
    </form>
    <?php
    $form = ob_get_clean();

    // Process form submission
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Retrieve form data
        $size = $_POST["size"];
        $color = $_POST["color"];
        $customPrinting = isset($_POST["custom_printing"]) ? true : false;
        $quantity = isset($_POST["quantity"]) ? intval($_POST["quantity"]) : 1;

        // Define base price and additional prices
        $basePrice = 20;
        $sizePrices = [
            'small' => 0,
            'medium' => 2,
            'large' => 4,
            'xl' => 6,
        ];
        $colorPrices = [
            'white' => 0,
            'black' => 2,
            'red' => 3,
            'blue' => 3,
        ];
        $customPrintingPrice = 5;

        // Calculate total price
        $totalPrice = ($basePrice + $sizePrices[$size] + $colorPrices[$color] + ($customPrinting ? $customPrintingPrice : 0)) * $quantity;

        // Display the total price
        $form .= "<p>Total Price for $quantity T-shirt(s): $totalPrice USD</p>";
    }

    return $form;
}
add_shortcode('tshirt_pricing_form', 'tshirt_pricing_form_shortcode');
```

Multiple Product Code:

```
// Add a shortcode for the product pricing form
function product_pricing_form_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="product">Product:</label>
        <select name="product" required>
            <option value="tshirt">T-shirt</option>
            <option value="hoodie">Hoodie</option>
            <!-- Add more product options as needed -->
        </select>

        <label for="size">Size:</label>
        <select name="size" required>
            <option value="small">Small</option>
            <option value="medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="large">Large</option>
            <option value="xl">XL</option>
        </select>

        <label for="color">Color:</label>
        <select name="color" required>
            <option value="white">White</option>
            <option value="black">Black</option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        </select>

        <label for="custom_printing">Custom Printing:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="custom_printing">

        <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
        <input type="number" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" required>

        <input type="submit" value="Calculate Price">
    </form>
    <?php
    $form = ob_get_clean();

    // Process form submission
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Retrieve form data
        $product = $_POST["product"];
        $size = $_POST["size"];
        $color = $_POST["color"];
        $customPrinting = isset($_POST["custom_printing"]) ? true : false;
        $quantity = isset($_POST["quantity"]) ? intval($_POST["quantity"]) : 1;

        // Define pricing rules for each product
        $pricingRules = [
            'tshirt' => [
                'basePrice' => 20,
                'sizePrices' => [
                    'small' => 0,
                    'medium' => 2,
                    'large' => 4,
                    'xl' => 6,
                ],
                'colorPrices' => [
                    'white' => 0,
                    'black' => 2,
                    'red' => 3,
                    'blue' => 3,
                ],
                'customPrintingPrice' => 5,
            ],
            'hoodie' => [
                'basePrice' => 40,
                'sizePrices' => [
                    'small' => 0,
                    'medium' => 3,
                    'large' => 6,
                    'xl' => 9,
                ],
                'colorPrices' => [
                    'white' => 0,
                    'black' => 4,
                    'red' => 5,
                    'blue' => 5,
                ],
                'customPrintingPrice' => 8,
            ],
            // Add more products and their pricing rules as needed
        ];

        // Calculate total price based on product and form input
        $totalPrice = $pricingRules[$product]['basePrice']
            + $pricingRules[$product]['sizePrices'][$size]
            + $pricingRules[$product]['colorPrices'][$color]
            + ($customPrinting ? $pricingRules[$product]['customPrintingPrice'] : 0)
            * $quantity;

        // Display the total price
        $form .= "<p>Total Price for $quantity $product(s): $totalPrice USD</p>";
    }

    return $form;
}
add_shortcode('product_pricing_form', 'product_pricing_form_shortcode');
```

Give me a solution to fix multiproduct issue